# Как изменить значение по умолчанию в gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на WP. В нем форма для заполнения бронирования.
Одно из полей gravity forms в виде селекта. В нем 5 значений на выбор. Когда заполняется форма, по умолчанию устанавливается одно из значений, но не то которое нужно.

Нигде нет возможности изменить. Default value нет такого поля.
Увидел вариант с передачей параметра через url, но и этого нет, в этом поле.

Подскажите пожалуйста как эту простую задачу выполнить?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: а чего не хватает вопросу?

Comment: Как минимум знаков препинания и форматирования. Без этого я эту простыню не могу читать.

Comment: знаки поставил для вашего удобства, а вот форматирование задает сам оверфлоу, не могу изменить он все слепливает в единое...